# Python: How is the docstring code running and is this the correct way to code a menu?

Tags: python, function, docstring, mainmenu

[Errors for this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnq3G.png)I don't understand how the code under the docstring is running. I am trying to make a main menu. I also keep getting errors under the comments

```
def main_menu():
    # Function for the interface where the user is presented with a menu and given the options requiring the user's input
    choice = input("""

    MainName
    
    R - Reporting
    I - Intelligence
    M - Monitoring
    A - About
    Q - Quit

    Choose an option: """)

    if choice == "R" or choice == "r":
        reporting()
    elif choice == "I" or choice == "i":
        intelligence()
    elif choice == "M" or choice == "m":
        monitoring()
    elif choice == "A" or choice == "a":
        about()
    elif choice == "Q" or choice == "q":
        quit()
    else:
        print(" ")
        print("Please try again")
        main_menu()
```

Is this a correct way to making a menu? The program runs with no error messages but I keep getting problems highlighted.

Comment: There's no docstring in that function. The string is the argument to the `input()` function. A docstring is a string all by itself in the function, not an argument or operand.

Comment: This is a perfectly normal way to implement a menu. Although I would convert the input to lowercase with `.lower()`, then you don't have to compare with two values.

Comment: Don't call `main_menu` recursively to implement a loop. Use a `while` statement instead.

Comment: It would also be normal to have a loop which goes round responding to an input until the user selects 'q'.

Comment: With recursion, a devious use can terminate your program (assuming that isn't what `quit` does anyway) by repeatedly choosing an invalid option until a `RecursionError` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You are using triple quotes in the input function that takes it as a string!
and for the menu it is correct but also checkout the case function newly launched in python version 3.11

Answer (score 0):

- You are using triple quotes in the input function that takes it as a string! and for the menu it is correct but also checkout the case function newly launched in python version 3.11
- use VsCode maybe your editor dosen't support it
- And use main_menu() function outside the if else block